# how to get values of a matrix in MATLAB where the indices are given in a nx2 array

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix `A` of size nRows x nCols.

I have a `nx2` matrix `B` which contains indices of the matrix `A`.
I want to get the values of `A` at the indices given in `B`.

lets say,

```
B = [1, 2;
     2, 3;
     3, 4]

A(1,2) = 1
A(2,3) = 2
A(3,4) = 1
```

I want to know any Matlab command which gives the following, given `A` and `B` (I don't want to use loops):

```
[1 2 1]
```

Comment: Ok I got it. I need to use sub2ind.

    A(sub2ind(size(A), B(:,1), B(:,2)))

Comment: general solution (for any-dimensional matrices) is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146082/indexing-of-unknown-dimensional-matrix)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
A(sub2ind(size(A),B(:,1),B(:,2)))
```

Comment: ...yes, thanks. I was not able to put an answer so I put it as comment.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want:

```
A = [1,2; 3, 4; 5, 6; 7,8; 9,0]; % this is your N by 2 matrix
B = [1,1; 1,2; 2,1; 3, 1; 4,2]; % these are your indexes
A(sub2ind(size(A), B(:,1), B(:,2)))

A =

 1     2
 3     4
 5     6
 7     8
 9     0



B =

 1     1
 1     2
 2     1
 3     1
 4     2

ans =

 1
 2
 3
 5
 8
```

Comment: what do you mean? I edit the answer to show you how general it is.