# MATLAB: How do you call a "cross-section" of an m-dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

In MATLAB, I have a multidimensional array of floats, `A`, with `m` dimensions; that is, its entries can be referenced with `A(n_1, n_2, ..., n_m)`.

I don't know if there is a good way to describe this using technical terms, so let me just use an example: if `A` is a 4-dimensional array, then

`A(:,:,1,:)` is a 1<sup>st</sup> cross section of `A` in the 3<sup>rd</sup> coordinate. Similarly,

`A(:,2,1,:)` would be the (2,1)<sup>th</sup> cross section of `A` in the 2<sup>nd</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> coordinates.

So my general question is, given an `A` whose dimensions are only determined at runtime, how do I reference the `(k_1,...,k_j)`<sup>th</sup> cross section of `A` in the `(c_1,...,c_j)` coordinates, where the `k`'s and `c`'s are also variables?

Comment: I asked a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146082/indexing-of-unknown-dimensional-matrix), but see now that it doesn't immediately solve your question. Ignore my vote to duplicate/close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to index `A` using a cell-array:

```
% Create array
A = rand(4,4,4,4);

% example k & c
k = [3 4 4];
c = [1 3 4];   


% Things that can go wrong
szA = size(A);
if numel(k) ~= numel(c) || any(c > ndims(A)) || any(k > szA(c)) 
    error('Invalid input.'); end


% Create the cell { ':' ':' ':' ... } with 
% the correct amount of repetitions
R = repmat({':'}, 1,ndims(A));

% Change it to { [3] ':' [4] [4] } 
% (depending on k and c of course)
R(c) = num2cell(k);

% use it to reference A
A(R{:})
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have matlab so I cant confirm this but I suspect the answer is:

```
function [val] = get_cross_value(A, cross_section, coord) {
     cross_A =  squeeze(A(cross_section{:}));
     val = squeeze(cross_A(coord));
}
```

My info came from http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/166539