# Using a colon for indexing in matrices of unknown dimensions

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, matrix-indexing

When indexing matrices in MATLAB, can I specify only the first or last *n* dimensions, and have all others dimensions "selected automatically"?

For example, I am writing a function which takes in an image, and displays it with `imshow`, which can either display a 3-D color image (*e.g* `1024×768×3`) or a 2-D monochrome array (*e.g* 1024x768).
My function does not care about how many color channels the image has, `imshow` will take care of that. All I want to do is pass parameters to select a single region:

```
imshow(frame(x1:x2, y1:y2, :))
```

What do I put in place of the last colon to say "*include all the others dimensions*"?

Comment: Does that last colon not work? Usually that is Matlab syntax for 'all'

Comment: @Schorsch is right: [Colon operator documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html)

Comment: No, because that will linearise the indices across the remaining dimensions. E.g. if frame is 5-dimensional, this will give a 1-dimensional result, as opposed to 3-dimensional as expected. I assume @sebf wants to preserve the trailing dimensions, in their existing structure?

Comment: related question: [Indexing of unknown dimensional matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146082)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **comma-separated-list expansion** together with the `':'` indexing.

Suppose your input is:

```
A = rand([7,4,2,3]);
```

To retrieve only first 2:

```
cln = {':', ':'};
A(cln{:})
```

To retrieve the last 3:

```
cln = {1, ':', ':', ':'};
A(cln{:})
```

Which can be generalized with:

```
sten            = 2:3;    % Which dims to retrieve
cln(1:ndims(A)) = {1};
cln(sten)       = {':'};
A(cln{:})
```

Comment: Very useful trick. Worth pointing out that you can have as many colons as you want, because the length is assumed to be 1 for any trailing dimensions that "don't exist".

Answer (score 1):

Following from Oleg's answer, here is a function that will work if you are selecting from several of the first dimensions. If other dimensions are needed, I think you can see how to modify.

```
function [dat] = getblock2(dat, varargin)
%[dat] = getblock(dat, varargin) select subarray and retain all others
%                                unchanged
%dat2 = getblock(dat, [1,2], [3,5]) is equivalent to
%       dat2 = dat(1:2, 3:5, :, :, :) etc.
%Peter Burns 4 June 2013

arg1(1:ndims(dat)) = {':,'};
v = cell2mat(varargin);
nv = length(v)/2;
v = reshape(v,2,nv)';
for ii=1:nv
    arg1{ii} = [num2str(v(ii,1)),':',num2str(v(ii,2)),','];
end
arg2 = cell2mat(arg1);
arg2 = ['dat(',arg2(1:end-1),')'];
dat = eval(arg2);
```