# Matlab last dimension access on ndimensions matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I have as entry a matrix which can have an several number of dimensions : `n × m` or `n × m × p` or `n × m × p × q` or ...

What I want to do is to access to the last dimension, something like:

```
data = input(:,:,1)
```

The problem is that the number of `:` can change.

Comment: Is the possible number of dimensions finite (and small)? If so, you could query the size of the matrix using the `size` function and have various cases using a `switch` statement.

Comment: Note that it is not recommended to use a variable called `input` as this is the name of a standard function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Indexing of unknown dimensional matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146082/indexing-of-unknown-dimensional-matrix)

Comment: @EitanT Though the solution to that question should be applicable here, this one is more specific. Hence 'shortcuts' may be taken here that are not viable solutions for the linked question.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin then perhaps it's a duplicate of [Using a colon for indexing in matrices of unknown dimensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924273/using-a-colon-for-indexing-in-matrices-of-unknown-dimensions). I go by the theory that most of the new questions are recycled... :)

Comment: @EitanT I agree that with some minor rewording that question would make this one obsolete. Have suggested a merge as that question seems to be worded better, whilst this one has a larger variety of answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should make use of the fact that indices into an array can be strings containing `':'`:

```
>> data = rand(2, 2, 2, 5);
>> otherdims = repmat({':'},1,ndims(data)-1);
>> data(otherdims{:}, 1)
ans(:,:,1) =
    7.819319665880019e-001    2.940663337586285e-001
    1.006063223624215e-001    2.373730197055792e-001
ans(:,:,2) =
    5.308722570279284e-001    4.053154198805913e-001
    9.149873133941222e-002    1.048462471157565e-001
```

See [the documentation on `subsref`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html) for details.

Comment: Very nice, I started out like this, but didn't find the `otherdims{:}` step!

Comment: You can use strings? Wow. +1

Answer (score 5):

It is a bit of a hack, but here is how you can do it:

```
data = rand(2,2,3);

eval(['data(' repmat(':,',1,ndims(data)-1) '1)'])
```

This will give (depending on the randon numbers):

```
ans =

      0.19255      0.56236
      0.62524      0.90487
```

Comment: Well seen. Let's clean up `eval`'s image. It's hackish but useful

Comment: No `eval` needed; MATLAB's default `subsref` allows string arguments for indices, provided those strings are `':'`; see my answer. Still, +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `shiftdim` to bring the last dimension to the first and index that one and reshape it back

```
x = rand(2,3,4,5,6);

sz = size(x);
A = shiftdim(x, numel(sz)-1);
B = reshape(A(1,:), sz(1:end-1));
```

and

```
>> isequal(B, x(:,:,:,:,1))
ans =
     1
```

or alternatively you can use `subsref` to index it:

```
B = subsref(x, substruct('()', [num2cell(repmat(':', 1, ndims(x)-1)) 1]))
```

Comment: +1, but that last step is a bit of an awkward way of doing it...see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Nice question!

Another possibility is to use linear indexing in blocks and then reshape:

```
x = rand(2,3,4,5); % example data
n = 2; % we want x(:,:,...,:,n)

siz = size(x);
b = numel(x)/siz(end); % block size
result = reshape(x(b*(n-1)+1:b*n),siz(1:end-1));
```

This seems to be the fastest approach in my computer (but do try yourself; that may depend on Matlab version and system)

Comment: +1 This is almost _exactly_ what I was typing up.  It's questions like this that make me want to stay glued to SO, but alas, I was away.  :(

Comment: @chappjc I knew you would like this question :-D

Answer (score 1):

I think this does it:

```
a = rand(2,2,2,3)

s = size(a)
r = reshape(a, [], s(end))
reshape(r(:,1), s(1:end-1)) %// reshape(r(:,2), s(1:end-1)) gives you a(:,:,:,...,2) etc...
```

I benchmarked against Dennis's (correct) answer and it gives the same result but doesn't need `eval` which is always worth avoiding if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case GNU Octave readers reach here.

@Rody Oldenhuis's answer can be written as an one-liner in Octave:

```
> data = reshape(1:8, 2, 2, 2);
> data({':'}(ones(1,ndims(data)-1)){:}, 1)
ans =

   1   3
   2   4
```

Here:

```
{':'}(ones(1,ndims(data)-1)){:}
```

means:

```
tmp = {':'};
tmp = tmp(ones(1,ndims(data)-1));
tmp{:}
```

Of couse, `repmat({':'},1,ndims(data)-1){:}` works also.